# How to run ts-node continuously

Tags: typescript, windows-services, ts-node

Previously I ran my app via the "node-windows" module as a windows service. Since adding TypeScript to my project I now run my app via "ts-node index.js" and can't use the node-windows module anymore. I am looking for a way to continuously run an app using ts-node.

I did try to use node-windows, whcih doesn't support ts-node.